# when to use extends or implements Comparable (Java) ? + why I cannot create object

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, compare, comparable

I am Studying Data Structures and I was asked to write a program that allows a store manager to manipulate an inventory , using 4 classes :   ListInterface , ExpandableArrayList ( a class that implements the interface) , class item ( which is the type stored in the Arraylist) , and of course, a Test class.

some methods require the use of **compareTo**. that is , being **Comparable** , but I don't know what class exactly should be Comparable ? 
and if I should write **Implements** or **extends** Comparable ?

these are the class headers I have right now :

```
public interface ListInterface<T extends Comparable <?super T >> {... }

public class ExpandableArrayList <T extends Comparable <? super T >>
implements ListInterface <T> { ...... } 

public class Item<T extends Comparable<T>> {... }
```

but for some reason, I cannot create an Object in the Test class.
when I type:

```
ListInterface<Item> inventoryList= new ExpandableArrayList<Item>();
```

I get the following errors :

```
Test.java:9: error: type argument Item is not within bounds of type-variable T 
ListInterface<Item> inventoryList= new ExpandableArrayList<Item> () ; 
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Comparable<? super T> declared in interface ListInterface


Test.java:9: error: type argument Item is not within bounds of type-variable T 
ListInterface<Item> inventoryList= new ExpandableArrayList<Item> () ;
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Comparable<? super T> declared in class ExpandableArrayList
```

How Can I solve this? what exactly should be changed? ..

thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You're going about this backwards. First, you're using generics instead of extending types. But most importantly: the classes that you need to be comparable are those that you compare. This should be a point in your design. If you don't need to compare/sort, don't use methods that require `Comparable`. If you do, then the thing that you compare/sort has to be `Comparable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T which is your type Item needs to implement Comparable. This will allow the ExpandableArrayList class to run the compareTo method on elements of type Item using the comparison provided by that class. When you implement compareTo from Comparable you have to give a way for comparing different Items, this should be based on the attributes of the Item class ideally.

```
public class Item implements Comparable<Item> {... }
```

This is what the class def would look like.

You have to write `implements` for interfaces and `extends` for classes.

Inheritance [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Interfaces [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html)

Comment: oh You really helped a lot !.. 
 I get it now , Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this -

```
public interface ListInterface<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {... }

public class ExpandableArrayList<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements ListInterface <T extends Comparable<? super T>> { ...... } 

public class Item implements Comparable<Item> {... }
```